# Mobile Safari updates for older iOS versions

Tags: safari, ios

I am aware that Safari for iOS is updated whenever iOS is updated.

For devices that cannot update to iOS 11:

- Can the Safari on those devices ever be update to recent versions (outside of the iOS upgrade)?
- Does the Safari for those devices receive any updates at all (e.g. security)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Safari only updates with iOS releases. If there is a very serious security concern Apple might release another (iOS) update to a previous version, that adds security fixes to Safari, but never Safari by itself, and no new features.

On MacOS however you can still download Safari updates for newer OSs.